# D3 Sunburst - Possible to show certain layers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I looking at Sunburst charts - namely from this example:

https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

I want to ask is it possible in D3 - to control the number of rings of that are shown. So say I only wanted to show up the the 2nd ring?

I've noticed this section of code

```
// For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
          return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
});
```

I've tried to append to this something along the lines of `d.depth = 2` however doesn't work:

```
// For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
          .filter(function(d) {
            if (d.depth = 2) {
              return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
            }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, filters need to return for every element. Try adding your depth check via a logical `&&`:

```
// For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.   
var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
    .filter(function(d) {
        return (d.dx > 0.005 && d.depth < 3); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
});
```

Comment: Great - that works - not sure why that didn't come to mind. Thanks!!

Comment: if i updated that variable to say `d.depth < 5` - how do i go about to refresh the chart? Is there a simple method?